# setVisiblitiy to an ImageView according to SQLite table column value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Im doing an app in Material Design and my goal is to get items form SQLite database and if an item row boolean is_checked is 1, then display this item with an ImageVIew in RecyclerView. I know this explanation is bit off so here is my code:

DbHandler:

```
 public void deleteProduct(String productname){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        String[] args = {productname};

        db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "= ?", args);
    }

public void changeProduct(Product product){

        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME,product.get_productname());
        values.put(COLUMN_ISCHECKED,product.is_checked());
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
```

My main activity where I communicate with database:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Product> productnames=new ArrayList<>();
    DBHandler dbhandler;
    Toolbar toolbar;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.productList);

        FloatingActionButton fab= (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);


 dbhandler=new DBHandler(this,null,null,1);
    adapter= new CustomAdapter(this,productnames,this,this);
    getProductsFromDb();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

And my CustomAdapter :

```
 private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Product> products= Collections.emptyList();
    public DbItemDeleteListener deleteListener;
    public DbItemChangeListener changeListener;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context,List<Product> products,DbItemDeleteListener deleteListener,DbItemChangeListener changeListener){
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.products=products;
        this.deleteListener = deleteListener;
        this.changeListener = changeListener;

    }



    public void check(int position){
        Product product=products.get(position);
        product.set_checked(true);
    }
    public void uncheck(int position){
        Product product=products.get(position);
        product.set_checked(false);
    }

    public Product getProduct(int position){
        Product product=products.get(position);
        return product;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);



        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product currentProduct=products.get(position);
        holder.productname.setText(currentProduct.get_productname());
        if(currentProduct.is_checked()) {
            holder.checkIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            holder.checkIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView productname;
        Button checkButton;
        Button deleteButton;
        ImageView checkIcon;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            productname= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProductName);
            checkButton= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkButton);
            deleteButton= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
            checkIcon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkIcon);




        }
```

As you can see I tried to check this field with the code:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product currentProduct=products.get(position);
        holder.productname.setText(currentProduct.get_productname());
        if(currentProduct.is_checked()) {
            holder.checkIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            holder.checkIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

But it wont work.

I have checked my database and check and uncheck methods works aka the database column value changes correctly.

Comment: alredy try change the "if(currentProduct.ischecked())" for a fixed value "if(true)"  and "if(false)", just for check  where is the problem

Comment: Solved it the problem was how I got the data from Db there was a line which allways returned false:Boolean.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ISCHECKED)));

Comment: Answer your own question, and put your solution, it can help another guy.